# Dell PowerEdge 1800 Server

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

Sorry about this silly question. I am more of a programmer than a system ad.

One of my colleagues gave me a Dell PowerEdge 1800 Server which I would like to use for some number crunching and sql server development server.

It has Linux installed on it. Is it generally possible to install windows xp on it? It seems to be impossible to boot from the CD. I could get hold of some other MS OS but would like to keep things as simple as possible. Any feedback welcome.

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: The thing is (as was in my case ending me up in here) PE 1800 is so old that it doesn't ship with a DVD drive, so it will boot CD-ROMs and not DVD-ROMs, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally speaking, the 1800 was designed with win2003 in mind (omitting Linux for now), so if you can get your hands on it - it'll be the perfect OS for that system. 
Still, since it's pretty much at EOL, 2008R2 is the current windows OS to use, and it can be used on a PE1800. 
To install it, download a dell installation CD, and boot from it - after guiding you through some HW setup questions, it'll ask for the windows DVD to continue.

Here's the link: 
http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&releaseid=R181938&SystemID=PWE_1800&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=17782&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=248199

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely generally possible to install Windows XP on a PowerEdgee 1800. However, in order to run a MS SQL Server, you would probably be much better of install Windows Server 2008. Windows XP is a desktop OS and not designed to handle server duties.

If you can't get it boot from the CD, check out the CD-ROM drive. Can it see other CD's in the drive? and read them? If no -> drive nackered (this is quite common). If yes -> CD nackered -> get a new one.